# como leer un archivo de configuración (app.config) desde mi local en c#

Tags: c#, .net

Necesito obtener la URL de una api que esta en mi app.config el cual esta de la siguiente forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="url" value="Aqui va la URL" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

pero mi archivo app.config debe estar almacenado en mi local (D:\Config\app.config). Como puedo obtener el valor de url desde mi código. Ya vi varios ejemplos pero todos se encuentran en la raíz del proyecto y utilizan lo siguiente para obtener la key:

```
string sAttr;
sAttr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("url");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes utilizar la clase ExeConfigurationFileMap y el método OpenMappedExeConfiguration de la clase ConfigurationManager:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"D:\Config\app.config";
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

string url = config.AppSettings.Settings["url"].Value;
```

crea una nueva instancia de ExeConfigurationFileMap, se establece la ruta del archivo de configuración en el atributo ExeConfigFilename, se abre el archivo de configuración utilizando OpenMappedExeConfiguration y se obtiene el valor de la clave "url" utilizando el método Settings de la sección AppSettings del objeto de configuración.